# How to use WebService of SQL Server 2008 Reporting Services

Tags: web-services, reporting-services

I created a report and published it to the Report Server 2008 that worked fine. I can call **http://*servername*:81/Reports** in my browser and view and export the reports. What I want to do now is write an application that uses the report to create a Excel file out of it.

According to the Reporting Services Configuration Manager the WebService of that Report Server is located at **http://*servername*:81/ReportServer**. When I open the link in my browser I can see the folders of the projects I created and deployed using Visual Studio.

But I can't find a web service endpoint there. In VS when I try to add a web reference no web service can be found there either.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you haven't specified the .asmx (web service) address...

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx) is from the SQL Server 2008 Books Online which should be useful. Also note the "Other Resources" link to [Building Application using the Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154699.aspx)...

Just checking the config file for one of our applications that uses the web service and the address stored is:

http://SERVER_NAME/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx

so yours might be:

http://SERVER_NAME:81/ReportServer/ReportService.asmx

Comment: The web service turned out to be located at ReportService2005.asmx and ReportExecution2005.asmx. The definition is available at ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl and ReportExecution2005.asmx?wsdl.
The example here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx) describes how to retrieve PDF/Excel/HTML/... data from your reports.

Thank you very much for pointing me there!!!

Comment: See Tobias answer above (+1) - ReportServices2005.asmx for SQLServer2008 - go figure... URL that finally worked for me was not on port 81, but rather default port 80... http://<hostname>/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx

Answer (score 2):

http://localmachinename:8080/ReportServer/reportservice2005.asmx?WSDL

Answer (score 2):

Check in the following folder:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.OSSSQL2008\Reporting Services\ReportServer\

There are two files:
-ReportService2005.asmx
-ReportExecution2005.asmx

Combine these with your url above "http://servername:81/ReportServer" to form the correct link to your webservice
i.e.
"http://servername:81/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl"